# iterator.next() returns alternate objects

Tags: java, hibernate, list, iterator

I am trying to execute `update` `HQL` query inside iterator for multiple records in java. But when I execute, it updates only alternate record by skipping next record. If I will just print iterator objects in log, without execute update query,it prints all objects. So **why it's skipping object each next, when I am executing `update` inside Iterator?**

My Code:

```
List<Integer> id = (List<Integer>) myList.list();//I've to update query for each id

for(Iterator < Integer > iter = id.iterator();iter.hasNext();){
           System.out.println("id: "+(Integer) iter.next());
           int ids =  (Integer) iter.next();
           Query query =session.createQuery("update MyTable set url =? where id=?);
           query.setParameter(0,url);
           query.setParameter(1,ids);
           query.executeUpdate();
    }
```

If I have 4 elements in `myList` it will just update for 2nd and 4th by skippint 1st and 3rd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to access the same iterator element multiple times in the same loop iteration, you shouldn't call `iter.next()` multiple times, since each call advances the iterator. Instead, call `iter.next()` once and store the result in a variable :

```
for(Iterator<Integer> iter = id.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    Integer currentID = iter.next();
    System.out.println("id: "+ currentID); 
    Query query = session.createQuery("update MyTable set url =? where id=?);
    query.setParameter(0,url);
    query.setParameter(1,currentID);
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Yes You are right, but I have already done this way just forgot to add here in example code, I have update code.

Comment: @niraj Your code still contains two `iter.next()` calls - `System.out.println("id: "+(Integer) iter.next());` and `int ids =  (Integer) iter.next();`

Comment: my 'ids' is same as your 'currentId' :) ans I have kept sys.out() for log purpose

Comment: @niraj You shouldn't call `iter.next()` in the println statement. Print `ids` instead.

Comment: yeah! by just removing sys.out()  statement, It inserts all records! Thanx @Eran for help! btw, Was it only thing causing issue?

Answer (score 1):

please use

```
List<Integer> ids = (List<Integer>) myList.list();
for (Integer id : ids) {
   Query query =session.createQuery("update MyTable set url =? where id=?);
   query.setParameter(0, url);
   query.setParameter(1, id);
   query.executeUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a good practice to use `while-loop` when using `Iterator`.

You should try:

```
List<Integer> ids = (List<Integer>) myList.list();
Iterator<Integer> iterator = ids.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    Integer id = iterator.next();
    System.out.println("id in this iteration is : "+ id); 
    Query query = session.createQuery("update MyTable set url =? where    id=?);
    query.setParameter(0,url);
    query.setParameter(1,id);
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

Hope it helps!